# p:dataExporter does not keep the sorting of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

The problem can be reproduced in PrimeFaces showcase:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml

```
<f:facet name="{Exporters}">
     <h:commandLink>
          <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/excel.png" width="24"/>
          <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="cars" />
     </h:commandLink>
</f:facet>
```

I have no idea from where the export gets the sorting that it is using.

Is there any way to make `p:dataExporter` to keep the same order as in `p:dataTable`?

**Edit:** My client noticed that if you click a column to sort the datatable then export keeps the sorting. That's good but how to keep the initial sorting?

Comment: What do you mean initial sorting ? is it arbitrary sorting ?

Comment: I mean the order they are in the datatable before it has been sorted by clicking a column. If you look at the PrimeFaces showcases sample the columns are not sortable. I would expect the export to export the records in the same order than they are in the data table.

Comment: This is a really valid question. Sadly no one can find a solution.